# bash: complete: filenames: invalid option name?

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc, source

When I try to source my .bashrc file after updating it with new environment variables, I get the following message: "bash: complete: filenames: invalid option name".
As I'm new to Ubuntu, I'm not quite sure what it means and how to get rid of it.
Any help is sincerely appreciated.
Thanks!

The contents of the .bashrc file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/home/anaconda3/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/tls_profiles/rivlib-2_3_0-x86_64-linux-gcc44/bin/:$PATH"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/tls_profiles/rivlib-2_3_0-x86_64-linux-gcc44/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/tls_profiles/riwavelib_wfm-2_3_0-x86-linux-gcc44/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: What exactly do you write in the terminal, when trying to source your .bashrc ?

Comment: source ~/.bashrc. This is the command I normally use.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`. So, i) comment out the last lines of your bashrc file (those dealing with completion, from `if ! shopt -oq posix; then` to the last `fi`) and try sourcing the file again. Do you have the same problem? If not, then 2) post the output of `grep filenames /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion `. 3) What changes did you make to `.bashrc`? Are you *sure* you only changed that file? I just tested it on my system and I get no errors, so the problem is almost certainly somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! I commented the lines out, sourced the .bashrc file and got no errors. Here is the output for grep filenames /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:

"# simply using 'compgen -f', because it honours spaces in filenames.
        compopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null
        [[ $result -gt 0 ]] && compopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null
    compopt -o filenames
        compopt -o filenames
        compopt -o filenames"

I just added two export path lines in the .bashrc and I'm quite sure that I did not change any other file.

Comment: @kps Please edit your question to add the output. (Click the "edit" button under your question.) Put four spaces at the start of each line for preformatted text.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
exec bash
```

And then

```
source .bashrc
```

it is working

Also I have added some export commands in .bashrc file. May be that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is because the version of `complete` command on the OS does not support `filenames` option. We can test it easily on **Centos7** since `complete` command on **Centos7** does not support `nosort` option.

TEST

```
> curl -sLO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redcursor/btc/master/ldc/_comp_ldc.sh
# it gives us error
> source _comp_ldc.sh 
-bash: complete: nosort: invalid option name
```

and in the source code here is configuration for it:

```
complete -o bashdefault -o nosort  -o default -F _comp_ldc ldc
```

if we remove `-o nosort` from source, it works with no error , so it should be:

```
complete -o bashdefault  -o default -F _comp_ldc ldc
```

---

NOTE that the same code on **Debian** or **Ubuntu** has no issue.

```
# no error
> source <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redcursor/btc/master/ldc/_comp_ldc.sh)
```